# ¿Por qué no puedo agregar un nuevo proyecto web en Firebase? ""Se produjo un error desconocido al crear el proyecto. Vuelve a intentarlo"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-messaging

Estoy intentando agregar un proyecto web en Firebase, sin embargo, luego de insertar todos los datos de entrada: Nombre de Proyecto, ID del Proyecto, Ubicación de Analytics y aceptar los términos y condiciones. La plataforma me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error: "Se produjo un error desconocido al crear el proyecto. Vuelve a intentarlo".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el error puede ser por limite en cantidad de proyectos, cuantos proyectos tienes con esa cuenta ?

Comment: Creé una nueva cuenta de correo en gmail. Esa cuenta no tiene asociado ningún proyecto.

Comment: @hdmq si fuera el limite de cantidad de proyectos, el mensaje sería precisamente ese, te sugiero crear el proyecto sin configurar Google Analytics y posteriormente lo configuras, el problema con ese mensaje de error es que es poco descriptivo y por experiencia son varias las causas.

Comment: @hdmq no debes cambiar a otro país como "Estados Unidos", puedes usar tu país, agregué una respuesta con esta información, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad este error, no es muy descriptivo, simplemente muestra el mensaje que muestras en tu imagen y es toda la información que indica, incluso no genera algún tipo de registro de error.

Esta es la versión en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Las causas pueden ser varias:

**•  El proyecto que tratas de registrar en `Firebase` fue importado o ya existe.**

**•  El proyecto debe ser creado con la cuenta que tenga el rol `Owner`, ya que este rol puede crearlos e incluso borrarlos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**•  En ocasiones el problema es la configuración de "Google Analytics", puedes crear tu proyecto sin esta configuración y posteriormente configurarlo.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**• Eliminar el proyecto y volver a crearlo.** Tal vez parezca un poco raro pero al no tener una descripción más detallada del problema, eliminando el proyecto y volviéndolo a crear, puedes crear el proyecto sin problema. Regularmente este detalle lo he experimentado en proyectos que fueron importados a `Firebase`.

---

Otra información:

Cuando llegas al limite de cantidad de proyectos, no es una  causa de este error, ya que el mensaje que se muestra en este caso es descriptivo e indica que has llegado al limite.

El definir cualquier país no debe influir en este problema, puedes usar tu país "Perú" sin ningún problema, simplemente cambiará el tipo de moneda en la cual se muestren algunos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y expandirte para evaluar las posibles causas. Tendré en consideración todos los apuntes acotados.

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedió que la Ubicación predeterminada de los recursos de GCP tenia que configurarla desde la configuración general del proyecto y desde esa parte se creó la base de datos.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]